# R Group ID's with overlapping time intervals

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with multiple groups within the dataset of IDs with Start & Stop datetimes.  What I'm trying to do is within each group identify where a subgroup occurred.  A subgroup within a group would be when two ID's overlap with their START & END datetime columns.  Below is script to create a sample dataset in R for one group.  What I want to do is within each group create a column called, "Grp" that groups those subgroups with overlapping START & END datetimes.

What I have...

```
structure(list(ID = c(1,2,3,4), START = structure(c(1490904000, 1490918400, 
1508363100, 1508379300), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), END = structure(c(1492050600, 1492247700, 
1509062400, 1509031800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("ID","START", 
"END"))
```

What I want is...

```
structure(list(ID = c(1,2,3,4), START = structure(c(1490904000, 1508379300, 
1508363100, 1490918400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), END = structure(c(1492050600, 1509031800, 
1509062400, 1492247700), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Grp = c(1,2,2,1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("ID","START", 
"END","Grp"))
```

I've tried using lubridate's interval, and finding an overlap that way, but no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atfter sorting by START, the condition for a new group is that the END of the previous row is less than the START of the next group:

```
head(df1$END, -1) < tail(df1$START,-1)

df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1,2,3,4), START = structure(c(1490904000, 1490918400, 
1508363100, 1508379300), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), END = structure(c(1492050600, 1492247700, 
1509062400, 1509031800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("ID","START", 
"END"))

df1
  ID               START                 END
1  1 2017-03-30 20:00:00 2017-04-13 02:30:00
2  2 2017-03-31 00:00:00 2017-04-15 09:15:00
3  3 2017-10-18 21:45:00 2017-10-27 00:00:00
4  4 2017-10-19 02:15:00 2017-10-26 15:30:00


df1a <- df1[ order(df1$START), ]
df1a$grp <- cumsum( c( 1, head(df1$END, -1) < tail(df1$START,-1) ))
 df1a
#---------------
  ID               START                 END grp
1  1 2017-03-30 20:00:00 2017-04-13 02:30:00   1
2  2 2017-03-31 00:00:00 2017-04-15 09:15:00   1
3  3 2017-10-18 21:45:00 2017-10-27 00:00:00   2
4  4 2017-10-19 02:15:00 2017-10-26 15:30:00   2
```

Here's a function that answers the first part of my response to the comment below:

```
grp_overlaps <- function(endings, beginnings){ 
                   cumsum(c( 1, head(endings, -1) < tail(beginnings, -1) )) }
```

Comment: This does answer my question thank you, but do you know how it could be modified to work with 3 ID's in a group and 2 in the other group?

Comment: It would not be at all difficult to make a function that accepts two datetime vectors and returns a grp vector. Then use the by() function or lapply(split(...)) to run the function within a factor grouping. The usual way to bind together the resulting separated dataframes in base R data management is to run do.call(rbind, ...) on the result. There are surely dplyr strategies that would also do the same manipulations, but I'm a "traditionalist". Search SO for "[r] apply function within groups".

Comment: Thank you very much!  I appreciate all of the help!